# C# DownloadFileAsync Callbacks Not Being Triggered

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

For some reason, the Async callbacks I've specified don't seem to get called. I've got the following in a Thread started by the original application thread:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), tempPath);
```

And for the callbacks I've got:

```
public void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("progress");
}

public void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("completed");
}
```

I've used breakpoints to verify that the downloadUrl and tempPath strings are both valid (and I can see the downloaded file in Windows Explorer). Any insight on why the callbacks wouldn't be trigger? Thanks!

Comment: It should work. What do you do after the DownloadFileAsync call ?

Comment: Why do you have a separate thread? The point of the async calls is that you don't need one.

Comment: No repro. Is this a console that exits immediately?

Comment: This has to be in a separate thread because it does other blocking operations above and I want the main UI to not block - and then the Async call because this part also has a UI component that I don't want blocking either. After the DownloadFileAsync call the thread ends, but it still doesn't work if I have that thread wait either. It is a DLL with a a Windows Form thrown in that is then including in another one of my projects.